# how to add google sign-in oauth to my website?

Tags: jquery, html, google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth

I want to add google sign-in in my website, i created my google developer console client ID and i found an official tutorial here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in which shows how its done, i did the same way tutorial shows but here i get nothing, i mean the button doesn't appears in my browser when i run the code.

here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Login with Google Account using JavaScript by CodexWorld</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="921258372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com">
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=renderButton"     async defer></script>
 <style>
 .profile{
 border: 3px solid #B7B7B7;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 350px;
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
 height: 160px;
  }
 .profile p{margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;}
 .head{margin-bottom: 10px;}
 .head a{float: right;}
 .profile img{width: 100px;float: left;margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}
 .proDetails{float: left;}
 </style>
 <script>
 function onSuccess(googleUser) {
 var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
 gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
    'userId': 'me'
});
//Display the user details
request.execute(function (resp) {
    var profileHTML = '<div class="profile"><div class="head">Welcome '+resp.name.givenName+'! <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></div>';
    profileHTML += '<img src="'+resp.image.url+'"/><div class="proDetails"><p>'+resp.displayName+'</p><p>'+resp.emails[0].value+'</p><p>'+resp.gender+'</p><p>'+resp.id+'</p><p><a href="'+resp.url+'">View Google+ Profile</a></p></div></div>';
    $('.userContent').html(profileHTML);
    $('#gSignIn').slideUp('slow');
});
 });
 }
  function onFailure(error) {
 alert(error);
 }
 function renderButton() {
 gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
'scope': 'profile email',
'width': 240,
'height': 50,
'longtitle': true,
'theme': 'dark',
'onsuccess': onSuccess,
'onfailure': onFailure
 });
 }
 function signOut() {
 var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
 auth2.signOut().then(function () {
$('.userContent').html('');
$('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
 });
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="gSignIn"></div>
 <div class="userContent"></div>
 <div class="divid" style="background:#ddd;height:30px;width:30px;">                </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instant of `<div id="gSignIn"></div>` please try to use `<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>` it should work well.

Comment: i tried this way first, and then i thought there would be some kind of problem with g-signin2 and i changed it to gSignIn, and i just tried g-signin2 again same result no changes

Comment: i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287669/google-signin-button-class-g-signin link will help you alot as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process in a slightly more elegant manner:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

function onSignOut(){
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut();
}
```

Comment: same result i still didn't get the button, can you try it in your own browser

Comment: and by following the tutorial you gave me, i get the button now but it is not  clickable

Answer (score 0):

okay, i found my solution, and thought help other facing it. i was accessing my file which i had this script on directly just by double clicking, but this acquires to be request through a running webserver, added my file to my servlet webcontent directory and accessed it through my browser and it works just perfect